# Is it possible to have the same product in 2 separate stores but have different downloadable links?

Tags: downloadable, sample

So here's the problem.

Store #1 sells music files and downloads.
Product 1
I have a Music file that is offered with 3 different options to buy.
1. mp3 option
2. wav version
3. all rights (zipped) this includes all 3

Store #2
Same product - but with only 1 option for download
I want to offer this same file but only offer the rights(zip) option 3-  but all 3 options show up in store #2

The reason is, the customer will not need option #2 in the second store because it included in option 3

Store #2 will only sell the rights to the music, no reason to buy the mp3 or wav verions since the're included.

Does anyone have a solution? I'd really be grateful if this is possible.

Answer (score 2):

You would have to extend the `downloadable_link` table as well as the Model related to it. I think it would be enough to add a `store_id` value to the links and filter the links according to the selected store.